# Understanding working of copy constructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

To understand working of constructor, copy constructor, destructor, I wrote the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
 class Cat
{
 public:
  Cat();
  Cat(Cat&);
  ~Cat();
  int itsage;
};
 
 Cat::Cat()
{
 cout << "Constructor called\n";
 cout << this << endl;
 itsage=2;
}
 
 Cat::Cat(Cat& theCat)
{
 cout << "Copy constructor called\n";
 cout << this << endl;
 itsage=theCat.itsage;
}

 Cat::~Cat()
{
 cout << "Destructor called\n";
 cout << this << endl;
}
 
 Cat myFunction(Cat Frisky)
{
 cout << "Inside myFunction\n";
 cout << "Frisky's address : " << &Frisky ; 
 cout << "\nFrisky's age: " << Frisky.itsage << "\n";
 Frisky.itsage=100;
 cout << "Reassigned Frisky's age: "<< Frisky.itsage << "\n";
 return Frisky;
}
 
 int main()
{
 Cat Mani;
 cout << "Mani's address : " << &Mani ;
 cout << "\nMani's age: " << Mani.itsage << "\n";
 myFunction(Mani);
 return 0;
}
```

I got output as follows:

```
Constructor called
0x61ff04
Mani's address : 0x61ff04
Mani's age: 2
Copy constructor called
0x61ff0c
Inside myFunction
Frisky's address : 0x61ff0c
Frisky's age: 2
Reassigned Frisky's age: 100
Copy constructor called
0x61ff08
Destructor called
0x61ff08
Destructor called
0x61ff0c
Destructor called
0x61ff04
```

Everything is ok to me except what is stored at address `0x61ff08` when there was second call to copy constructor? Means we can see what is stored at addresses `0x61ff0c` and `0x61ff04` which are nothing but `Frisky` and `Mani`. Then what is that invisible thing at `0x61ff08`?

I thought of making that object visible by making a small change in `main` function.

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std; 
 class Cat
{
 public:
  Cat();
  Cat(Cat&);
  ~Cat();
  int itsage;
};
 
 Cat::Cat()
{
 cout << "Constructor called\n";
 cout << this << endl;
 itsage=2;
}
 
 Cat::Cat(Cat& theCat)
{
 cout << "Copy constructor called\n";
 cout << this << endl;
 itsage=theCat.itsage;
}

 Cat::~Cat()
{
 cout << "Destructor called\n";
 cout << this << endl;
}
 
 Cat myFunction(Cat Frisky)
{
 cout << "Inside myFunction\n";
 cout << "Frisky's address : " << &Frisky ; 
 cout << "\nFrisky's age: " << Frisky.itsage << "\n";
 Frisky.itsage=100;
 cout << "Reassigned Frisky's age: "<< Frisky.itsage << "\n";
 return Frisky;
}
 
 int main()
{
 Cat Mani;
 cout << "Mani's address : " << &Mani ;
 cout << "\nMani's age: " << Mani.itsage << "\n";
 Cat Sweety = myFunction(Mani); 
 cout << "Sweety's age : " << Sweety.itsage ;
 return 0;
}
```

But received an error as follows :

```
ppp.cpp: In function 'int main()':
ppp.cpp:47:25: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'Cat&' from an rvalue of type 'Cat'
  Cat Sweety = myFunction(Mani);
               ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
ppp.cpp:19:2: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'Cat::Cat(Cat&)'
  Cat::Cat(Cat& theCat)
  ^~~
```

I really didn't get what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code returns a copy of `Frisky` from `myFunction`, that is where the additional copy comes from.

Your second code doesn't work because your copy constructor erroneously takes a non-const reference and you can't pass the temporary value returned from `myFunction` to a non-const reference.

Not directly related to your question but you should obey the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and implement the assignment operator too.

Comment: Bit strange.. when we pass ```Mani ```, it was ok to copy constructor but when we return ```Frisky``` it had problem.. why so?

Comment: Mani isn't a temporary so can be bound to a non-const reference

Comment: Thanks.. one last thing.. may sound ugly but I had this doubt for some time in my mind.. copy of ```Frisky``` is stored at ```0x61ff08```and later it also got destroyed.. then what abt copy of ```Mani``` (which was created when we made call to ```myFunction```).. doesn't it get stored somewhere or destroyed?

Comment: The copy of Mani is Frisky, it's stored on the stack of `myFunction` and is destroyed at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

```
Cat(Cat &);
```

Use `const` here.

```
Cat(const Cat &);
```

Not related but consider using initialisation like this.

```
Cat Sweety{myFunction(Mani)};
```